# CSS HTML: Text Wraps in Chome: Works fine in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have html and css as posted in http://jsfiddle.net/SLs47/ . When I open it in Chrome the title text get wraped (and misaligns) while **zoom** is increased. However it works fine in Firefox. Please see the following images.

What need to be altered inorder to make it working?

[image]

Chrome [image]

---

Answer (score 0):

Although i couldn't reproduce the error, i think changing `#titleinfo` 's `display` property to `inline-block` from `inline` should prevent it from wrapping.